# GRUB "USB lock" for Linux Full Disk Encryption

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, encryption, usb, grub

Hy everyone.

I'm investigating the possibility of using something like USB hardware locking dongles (like [these ones](https://www.microcosm.com/products/dinkey-pro-fd) used for software locking and licensing) to provide the key that Grub asks for when booting a linux server with full disk encryption.

Is there something like this?

**Note** Because I may be searching for the wrong solution, here is the problem description:

- Provide a Linux VM (for VMWare ESXi) with full disk encryption
  so that acess to the hd/disk data is not possible (decryption is done
  on-the-fly when the system is running)
- The VM can be booted/rebooted without manual intervention
- Encryption key is not exposed by the solution used (I'm aware that some similar solutions put the key on the MBR for Grub to pick up OR use a normal USB drive to store it in plaintext)

Hope everything is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Creating dependancies for a *virtual* server on the presence of specific *physical* hardware dongles is a huge nuisance IMHO, regardless if you use them for licensing servers or something else.

Comment: Hy @HBruijn. I understand, but at the moment it's more important to secure the data.